# Playing and SkipNext Song from Playlists with MPMusicPlayerController in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, mpmusicplayercontroller

I have playlists songs in `NSArray` and show that songs in my `UITableView` like following pic.

[image]

In my case, when i select one song from `UITableView` , i want to play that song with `MPMusicPlayerController's` `applicationMusicPlayer`.

I mean when i select **american idiot** from `UITableView` , i want to play American idiot with `MPMusicPlayerController's`

And when i tap below Skip button , it's must be play next song like jesus of suburbia.

Here is my code that load songs to UITableView

```
self.player = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];

    MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery playlistsQuery];
    MPMediaPredicate *predicate = [MPMediaPropertyPredicate predicateWithValue:@"GreenDay" forProperty:MPMediaPlaylistPropertyName comparisonType:MPMediaPredicateComparisonContains];

    [query addFilterPredicate:predicate];

    self.arrayOfSongs = [query items];
```

i think you understand what i mean.
I want to do all music button work like iOS build in Music app and play song when i select song from `UITableView`.

I am trying anyting , but i didn't find solutions that can solve my problem.

Please help me to do like that.

Thanks you. :)

Comment: can we get the selected playlists from the iPod music?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your NSArray was populated with MPMediaItems from a MPMediaItemCollection, this is actually fairly simple once you know what you need to configure. First, create a iVar, preferably NSUInteger to store the index of the currently playing track. This will be necessary to go from one track to another in order.

Second, it's hard to tell from your post wether the track titles are being read from the media items in the collections or are if they're just statically placed on the table, but I've included an example of how to read a track title from the media items in the array and set that value as the cells text using `valueForProperty`.

And finally, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` is configured below to demonstrate of the set the unsigned integer that you've already created to the value of the selected cell. Both `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and the two IBActions I've created both modify the value of this index and then call the void I've created "stopCurrentTrackAndPlaySelection" which stops the currently playing track, typecasts MPMediaItem to the object at that index, and then starts playing again.

If you need more clarification just ask :)

**Side note:** I recommend that you store a copy of the media pickers selection (MPMediaItemCollection) in a NSMutableArray instead of NSArray, or MPMediaItemCollection directly. This will allow you to add or remove tracks on the fly without having to stop playback.

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [myArrayOfTracks count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[(MPMediaItem *)[myArrayOfTracks objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle]];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    indexOfCurrentlyPlayingTrack = indexPath.row;
    [self stopCurrentTrackAndPlaySelection];
}

- (IBAction)nextTrack:(UIButton *)sender
{
    indexOfCurrentlyPlayingTrack ++;
    [self stopCurrentTrackAndPlaySelection];
}

- (IBAction)previousTrack:(UIButton *)sender
{
    indexOfCurrentlyPlayingTrack --;
    [self stopCurrentTrackAndPlaySelection];
}

- (void)stopCurrentTrackAndPlaySelection
{
    [myMPMusicPlayerController stop];
    [myMPMusicPlayerController setNowPlayingItem:(MPMediaItem *)[myArrayOfTracks objectAtIndex:indexOfCurrentlyPlayingTrack]];
    [myMPMusicPlayerController play];
}
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. i am testing with your code.
But when i select songs from UItableView , it's doesn't play anything.How could i do that brother?

Comment: @Onigiri The code I've provided demonstrates how to do that, as well as next/back functionality.

Comment: @Onigiri I'm having a hard time understanding what your problem is then. In your original post it sounded like you were having a hard time changing the currently playing track by selecting cells in the table. Is the code you've added not working? Need more details.

Comment: hehe sorry for my bad english bro. I think i got a tips from your answer .. i really appreciate for your answer. :)

Comment: @Onigiri No problem, and glad to hear it! If my answer helped don't forget to mark as correct :)

Comment: hello bro , for the first time i am not playing anything , so when i select song from UITableView , it's doesn't play anything.I mean when i launch my app and to start play from selected song.

Comment: @Onigiri selecting the song should work provided that you've properly configured your MPMusicPlayerController, can you show the code for how you've set it up?

Comment: It's ok when playing song to skip and select song from UITableView. However for the first time load , that select song is not play.

Comment: Oh i got it from your answer. Thank you very much brother. :)

Comment: @MickMacCallum can we get the selected playlists from the iPod music?